# Could not find goal 'devmode' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, command-prompt

I am a beginner in GWT and Maven. I created a new GWT Application project in Eclipse. Then, I converted that project into Maven Project by right-click on Project name => **Configure** => **Convert to Maven Project** and I saw that a pom file was generated for that project. Next, I run as project as Maven build but it was not compiled since a goal was not specified there. Actually, I don't understand what exactly have I to write under that goal section, therefore, I wrote **package** under that and then again I built maven and it compiled successfully.

After that, I tried to run this maven project in Command Prompt on the SuperDevMode using the 2nd step mentioned on [Run the GWT Project](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/polymer-tutorial/create.html#Setting%20up%20a%20new%20project.) under the **Setting up a new project** section. But while following these steps on Command Prompt, I got an error that devmode could not be found. Here is my Command prompt log:

```
C:\Users\TEST>cd eclipse-workspace/MyWebApp

C:\Users\TEST\eclipse-workspace\MyWebApp>mvn war:exploded
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.1.0:exploded (default-cli) @ abcdef ---
[INFO] Exploding webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [abcdef] in [C:\Users\TEST\eclipse-workspace\MyWebApp\target\abcdef-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [63 msecs]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.920 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-30T11:24:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\TEST\eclipse-workspace\MyWebApp>mvn gwt:devmode
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.301 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-30T11:25:02+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'devmode' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1 among available goals clean, compile, compile-report, css, debug, eclipse, eclipseTest, generateAsync, help, i18n, mergewebxml, resources, run, run-codeserver, source-jar, test -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyWebApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>abcdef</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <name>MavenApp</name>
  <description>It is a maven app</description>
</project>
```

I searched a lot to resolve this error but found no solution for that issue. Please help me to fix this issue as I am very confused on how to fix it.

**Edit:** After further study, I used `mvn gwt:run` as an alternative to the command `mvn gwt:devmode`, but still I got another error on command prompt as given below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:run (default-cli) on project MyWebApp: The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:run are missing or invalid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve this issue by copying some dependencies, plugin, and configuration from the pom.xml file (which is generated in the project created by the webAppCreator using maven) to the pom.xml file of my project created in the Eclipse. So, this is my pom.xml file created finally:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyPersonalProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyPersonalProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>

    <!-- Setting maven.compiler.source to something different to 1.8
         needs that you configure the sourceLevel in gwt-maven-plugin since
         GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8 (see gwt-maven-plugin block below) -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- Don't let your Mac use a crazy non-standard encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc-6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>import-sources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>import-test-sources</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>mypackage.MyPersonalproject</moduleName>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
               a different source language for java compilation -->
          <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
          <!-- Compiler configuration -->
          <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
            <arg>-compileReport</arg>
            <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <!-- DevMode configuration -->
          <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
          <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
          <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
          <startupUrls>
            <startupUrl>MyPersonalProject.html</startupUrl>
          </startupUrls>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run this application using maven in the Command Prompt, it ran successfully except showing 2 or 3 warnings in the Command Prompt log. Also, I noticed that the SNAPSHOT generated in the version is different for the pom.xml created by Eclipse as compared to the one created by the maven project on command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information than `gwt:devmode`, Maven will try to find an appropriate plugin, based on its default settings. It happens that a *gwt-maven-plugin* exists with *org.codehaus.mojo* as groupId, fitting in Maven built-in plugin resolution.

But this is not the plugin you're looking for.

You are probably trying to use [this one](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/usage.html), so just add this to your *pom.xml*, in the `<plugins>` section:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-rc-8</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <moduleName>com.example.app.App</moduleName>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Adapting the *moduleName* if needed.